# Math pow returns 1.0

Tags: java, android

I am very new in java dev so it might be a trivial question:

```
double u130 = (1 / 30);
double q1 = Math.pow(1.025, u130);
```

the q1 is equal 1.0, but it should be 1.0008234259155

u130 = 0.0 also wrong.

I my understanding double is made for so many decimal places, so where is the problem?

By the way I am testing on Android device, this should be a limitation?!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1 / 30` is the *euclidian division*, so the result is `0` (as `int`).

Instead, you need a *real* division:

```
double u130 = 1. / 30;
double q1 = Math.pow(1.025, u130);
```

Comment: `1.0` instead of `1.`

Comment: `1.` is sufficient.

Comment: i never test it before, its good to know new things, :))

Comment: `1.` is barely legible and kind of hides the fact it's a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem :

```
    double u130 = (1 / (double)30);
    double q1 = Math.pow(1.025, u130);
```